# g++ and gcc differences

Tags: g++

I am trying to compile CPP code on an Ubuntu machine. I read somewhere that g++ is included in gcc. so in CodeBlocks I included the GNU GCC compiler. Codeblocks returned an error saying that g++ was not found. Is g++ another seperate compiler?

Answer (score 0):

g++ is for compiling C++, gcc is for compiling C. Two different compilers for two different languages!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with g++ but g++ is a C++ compiler and C++ is an extension of the C language so all C code can be compiled with a C++ compiler. So you could say that g++ contains a C compiler but saying that g++ contains gcc isn't correct I think.

Answer (score 0):

Both `g++` and `gcc` programs are from the same free software project, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). However, on Ubuntu you have several different packages for them, so install the `g++-4.6` or the `g++` package with `gcc-4.6` or `gcc` one. (if you don't install both, you won't be able to compile both C & C++).

Both programs can compile C and C++ files, assuming the C files are suffixed with `.c` and the C++ ones with `.cc` or  `.cpp` (etc..).

But they won't do exactly the same things, in particular, they won't link the same default libraries.

To understand what they do, you can run

```
gcc -v -Wall -g myprog.cc -o myprog
```

and

```
g++ -v -Wall -g myprog.cc -o myprog
```

and you'll see the differences. The `-v` flag often means "verbose".